# Selenium drag and drop in invisible Chrome browser running in Windows

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

Running on python 2.7.13, with the help of Windows scheduler in background (user is not required to keep himself logged in) with selenium 3.9.0 and Chrome driver 76 with Chrome browser 76. Drag and drop feature is not working in *background* execution, whereas it is working in a visible window. Is this expected result?

Tried the code with ActionChains by holding element 1, moving to element 2, and releasing the hold.

```py
def foo(xpath1, xpath2):
    el = br.find_element_by_xpath("xpath1")
    el2 = br.find_element_by_xpath("xpath2")
    ac = ActionChains(br)
    ac.click_and_hold(el) \
        .move_to_element_with_offset(el2, 1, 1) \
        .release().perform()
```

My expectation is that this code should be able to drag and drop the element 1 on top of element 2 when running in background mode.

Comment: I have not tried it but the docs say you can use [`drag_and_drop(source, target)[source]`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.drag_and_drop)